# Getting JQuery Masonry to work with Drupal 7 Views

Tags: 7, javascript

I want to do this without porting the fluid grid module to 7 from 6. I can't for the life of me get a view page of images to work with [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/).

Does anyone has experience with this and know how to get it working with just masonry.js and not a module?

Thanks

Comment: Why no module?  [Masonry](http://drupal.org/project/masonry) would do everything you need.

Answer (score 6):

There's actually a [Masonry](https://drupal.org/project/masonry) module now

> Makes the jQuery Masonry plugin available to Drupal as a library.

Answer (score 1):

i just took a short look at masonry ..,
you can add the masonry.js to your theme, and add a custom .js with a [drupal.behavoir](http://drupal.org/update/modules/6/7#drupal_behaviors) containing your masonry code - but this will be used on every page.
the

you can do the same in a custom module for dedicated includes; only when your view is displayed.

Comment: Could you explain in detail how to do it? Does it require to make a module from scratch?

Comment: yeah - a custom module from scratch, using fe. [hook_views_post_render](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!views!views.api.php/function/hook_views_post_render/7) to attach the js for your identified view.